# Code analysis tool for Apache cordova app development?

Tags: cordova

I wants to use code analysis tool like sonarqube for Apache cordova development.
It should show the bugs/code smells from .ts files.
Any suggestions which will be the right tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tslint with additional rules from ionic: https://github.com/ionic-team/tslint-ionic-rules